# my MiKTeX can't find the package fancyhdr

Tags: errors, miktex, installing

I have tried installing it but it just says not found like this

```
LaTeX Error: File `fancyhdr.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: kpsewhich fancyhdr.sty

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.12
```

Then I tried to manually install it through MikTeX package manager(admin) and it just give me this message

```
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: The MiKTeX web service has rejected your request. Possible reason: too many requests arriving from your IP address.
Data: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Service Unavailable</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Service Unavailable</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\PackageManager.cpp
Line: 132
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Microsoft Windows 8 Home Premium Edition, 64-bit (build 9200)
Invokers: explorer
SystemAdmin: yes
PowerUser: no
Root0: C:\Users\Benjamin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\Benjamin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root3: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\Benjamin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\Benjamin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\Benjamin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
```

so hope u know how to do it

Comment: Talk to your admin about the network error. There's nothing we can do.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: well now it work for some strange reason now but thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

I had this error for quite a while this morning. The only way to handle this is to wait some time. The problem is lying on the server side as changes of IP or election of another mirror did not do the trick here.

In case, you get this error again, you may want to report that to the [maintainer](http://miktex.org/contact).